# make google map api v2 addDomListener work in IE

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

i have some troubles using google map api v2. What i want is to be able to go with the mouse over the tooltip.
   Below is the code that i have. In firefox works but i have to move the mouse very gently over the tooltip, if i go to fast it will hide (solved : added a delay on the mouseout function, and there check if I trigger the tooltip or not) and the worst part it doesn't wark at all in IE. If i go over the pin point i will be able to see the tooltip, but i can't go with the mouse over it.

```
function createHotelSearchMarker(point, number, message) {
    var newIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
    wIcon.image = imageChart + "chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.5|0|CCCCCC|10|_|" + number + "&ext=.png";
    var marker = new GMarker(point, {icon: newIcon, clickable:true, zIndexProcess:importanceOrder});
    marker.importance = 1;  
    /*add listener for mouseover*/
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
        marker.openExtInfoWindow(
            map,
            "mapInfoWindow",
            "<div id='tooltip'>" + message + "</div>",
            {beakOffset: 3}
        );
        marker.setImage(imageChart + "chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.5|0|FF0000|10|_|" + number + "&ext=.png");
        marker.importance = 2;
        marker.setLatLng(marker.getLatLng());

        /*i added a dom listener for the tooltip*/
        if(document.getElementById("tooltip") != null) {

            GEvent.addDomListener(document.getElementById("tooltip"), "mouseover", function(){
                isFiredByDivListener = 1;
                GEvent.trigger(marker,"mouseover");
            });

            GEvent.addDomListener(document.getElementById("tooltip"), "mouseout", function(){
                isFiredByDivListener = 0;
                GEvent.trigger(marker,"mouseout");
            });
        }
    });

    /*add a listener for mouse out*/
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
        map.closeExtInfoWindow();

        marker.setImage(imageChart + "chst=d_map_spin&chld=0.5|0|CCCCCC|10|_|" + number + "&ext=.png");
        marker.importance = 1;
        marker.setLatLng(marker.getLatLng());

    });
    return marker;
    }

the marker will be return and 


if (marker != null){
                map.addOverlay(marker);
            }
```

Thank you for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you've got this going on, i.e. a potential problem where you could be recursively triggering the marker mouseover.  I'd suggest moving the two addDomListener event listeners outside of the marker's event listener.

```
GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
        ...
            GEvent.addDomListener(document.getElementById("tooltip"), "mouseover", function(){
                GEvent.trigger(marker,"mouseover");
            });
```

Comment: that was also my first thought, but unfurtunately it doesn't work neither in IE nor in Firefox